# Ajax call opens thousand of mysql connections

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a chatting application in which I have to refresh two tables.

I am refreshing these tables after  seconds using the AJAX.

But the problem is that it is opening thousands of sql connections.

My code is in main php page

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        refreshTable();

    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#table_data').load('get_table.php', function(){
            setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
        $('#table_data_notification').load('notification_table.php', function(){
            setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });

    }
  </script>
```

Here my notification_table.php code, the file that will return the table

```
<?php
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION["Username"];
?>
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Chat ID</th>
    <th>From</th>

    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <?php
    $s = 1;
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass =  "";
    $db   = "video";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Could Not connect to database".mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($db,$con);

    $name=$_SESSION["Username"];
    $sql = "  SELECT * FROM chat_detail WHERE `to_user`='$name' and clicked='no' ORDER BY id DESC ";

    $getData = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetchData = mysql_fetch_array($getData))
    {
    ?>
<tr class="gradeX" id="rowID<?php echo $s?>">
    <td><?php echo $fetchData['id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fetchData['from_user']?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $fetchData['chat_date']?></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Chat</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
$s++;
}
$con->close();
?>

</tr>

</tbody>
```

Please suggest the solution.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Umair found the solution...I have used

```
$(function() {
var prevAjaxReturned = true;
var xhr = null;
var xhr1 = null;
setInterval(function() {
    if( prevAjaxReturned ) {
        prevAjaxReturned = false;
    } else if( xhr ) {
        xhr.abort( );
    }
    else if( xhr1 ) {
        xhr1.abort( );
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: "get_table.php",
        success: function(html) {
            // html is a string of all output of the server script.
            $("#table_data").html(html);
            prevAjaxReturned = true;
        }

    });
    xhr1 = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        url: "notification_table.php",
        success: function(html) {
            // html is a string of all output of the server script.
            $("#table_data_notification").html(html);
            prevAjaxReturned = true;
        }

    });

  }, 1000);
});
```

and on backend mysql_pconnect();

Comment: No, you did _not_ get the solution by using `mysql_pconnect`.  You did it by fixing your exponential recursion.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `mysql_pconnect()` that will do much better

Comment: @AmitKhurana this is insufficient to stop your page loads from blowing up exponentially.  In practise you've actually fixed the exponential load some other way, and the `mysql_pconnect` will make little difference.   I've written PHP code that uses non-persistent MysQL connections and it works perfectly happily.

Answer (score 3):

> But the problem is that it is opening thousands of sql connections.

Yes, of course it is, because for every call to `refreshTable` it's calling itself *twice* with the timer, causing an 2^n exponential explosion in the number of calls.

Unfortunately `.load` doesn't offer a "promise" interface, but you could use this:

```
function refreshTable() {
    $('#table_data').load('get_table.php', function() {
        $('#table_data_notification').load('notification_table.php', function(){
            setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

i.e. only perform the second load once the first has finished, and only then start the timer *once*.

If you really want the two `.load` operations to run in parallel, you could try this:

```
// plugin to wrap `.load` to it returns a promise
(function($) {
    $.fn.loadPromise = function(url) {
        var $this = this;
        return $.Deferred(function(def) {
            $this.load(url, def.resolve);
        }).promise();
    }
})(jQuery);

function refreshTable() {
    $.when(
        $('#table_data').loadPromise('get_table.php'),
        $('#table_data_notification').loadPromise('notification_table.php')
    ).then(function() {
        setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Write database connection  and close connection code in separate function. then call the function in ajax. it will reset connection on every call.

Comment: @MaDHaNMinHo I haven't addressed the PHP code - only the exponential explosion in calls to `.load`

Comment: i faced the same problem in jsp on ajax call. so i wrote separate function. because each time load is executed a new connection is opened existing connection wont close. so use separate function.

Comment: @Alnitak the code is not working..... I have written this code$(document).ready((function($) {
    $.fn.loadPromise = function(url) {
        var $this = this;
        return $.Deferred(function(def) {
            $this.load(url, def.resolve);
        }.promise();
    }
    )(jQuery);

    function refreshTable() {
        $.when(
            $('#table_data').loadPromise('get_table.php'),
            $('#table_data_notification').loadPromise('notification_table.php')
        ).then(function() {
                setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
            });
    }

Comment: I have posted it as answer ... accept answer if that helped

Comment: @AmitKhurana there was a missing `)` before the `.promise()` call.

Comment: @Umair no, that only "fixes" the large number of concurrent connections, but completely fails to fix the underlying problem which is the exponential explosion in the number of calls to the "recursive" function.  Fixing the latter would make the code work perfectly well, with no need to use `mysql_pconnect`.

Comment: @Alnitak it is still not working...I think you are missing $ before function but still it is not working... and what is the use of (jquery)??

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have marked other one correct because the above answer is not working.

Comment: @AmitKhurana Be my guest. Both Alnitak and me correctly identified the root cause of your problem. You've acknowledged this by completely rewriting your AJAX code in your question update. The solution you've currently accepted treats one of the symptoms rather than the underlying cause, and by accepting it you're not only rendering a disservice to yourself, but also to the community at large.

Comment: @AmitKhurana the code reading `$(function($) { .. } )(jQuery)` is standard boilerplate for adding a new jQuery plugin.  Please don't just say "it doesn't work".  Include error messages, debugging information, etc.

Comment: @AmitKhurana  OK, I found one more missing `}` in the plugin code, which you could probably have trivially found for yourself if you had looked in the debugger.

Comment: I've tested the plugin, I can assure you that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Except JS nested calls, probably you need to read about some patterns like Singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and create a static class to make a pool connection to MySQL. Also, there is already a pretty good library idiorm to query a DB. (https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)